# Notation for orbits in Ergodic Theory

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, group-actions, ergodic-theory

Consider a map $T:X\to X$ from a set to itself. In ergodic theory, we say that the orbit of a point $x\in X$ is the set \begin{equation} \{x,Tx,T^2x,T^3x,\cdots\}.\end{equation}
Is there any standard nomenclature for such a set? I expect there is, since for example in group theory there is notation to describe an orbit, but I can't find any ergodic theory analogue.

Comment: I've seen $\operatorname{orb}(x)$ used for this

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware, there is no standard notation for orbits in dynamics or ergodic theory. Here are some common notations:

- $\operatorname{orb}(x)$ (as FShrike commented),
- $O(x)$,
- $\mathcal{O}_x(T)$ (this is what I personally use; it signals that $\mathcal{O}(T)$ is the orbit partition w/r/t the transformation $T$, and $\mathcal{O}_x(T)$ is the cell in the orbit partition passing through $x$),
- $\mathbb{Z}x$, similar to how one would denote it in group theory.

In your case the orbit is one sided, to denote this it is common to decorate the above with e.g. a $+$ or $\geq0$.